# Want to show hierarchical data(parent-chid) in data grid(excel) in WPF C#.How to do it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

We want to show hierarchical data(parent-child) in data grid(excel) in WPF C#.
Features needed are:
1) User can add or delete the row at any level(parent level/child level).
2) Data shold be in sorted order
3) grouping nad filtering provided

We have also find out the **Extended Grid** control but it will not given facility to add or delete row at any level and edit that row.

So,Could any one tell me is there any existing control present to satisfy my requirement?

Comment: Refer the link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi Ganesh,
Thanks for reply.
But it is not satisfying my requirement because hierarchical data supported upto n -Level.
And we want to add/delete the row at any level.
Please let me know if you have any more solution on this.